# Wordpress: Conditional Statements same for blog and frontpage?

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I have added a video to the homepage header of my wordpress theme but it also displays on the blog page.

my php is

```
if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
    echo ' 
        <div class="overlay-caption">
            <h1 class="home-h1">Join Us</h1>
            With over 30 years of experience your adventure with us will be fun, memorable and help you pursue your passion for photography.
        </div>
        <div class="videoWrapper">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3tmFvHviYcY?rel=0&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&controls=0&loop=1&playlist=3tmFvHviYcY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen autoplay="1"></iframe>
        </div>';
} 
else {}
?>
```

Now if i try only is_front_page it doesn’t appear on the homepage, if I try is_home it work but also shows up on the blog page.

I want the header on the blog page to be a standard header image, and I just want the homepage to display the video from the code I have included. Do I need to switch the conditional statement to a different order, or do I have the syntax completely wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: i have provided you with a clear explanation about your requirement. let me know if you face any hindrance in development :)

Comment: i have provided you with explanations for `is_page()`, `is_home()` and `is_front_page()`. Hope so any one will make a trick for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic difference between the `is_home()` and `is_front_page()` is as follows.

**is_home()**

The blog homepage is the page that shows the time-based blog content of the site.

is_home() is dependent on the site’s “Front page displays” Reading Settings ‘show_on_front’ and ‘page_for_posts’.

If a static page is set for the front page of the site, this function will return true only on the page you set as the “Posts page”.

**is_front_page()**

This Conditional Tag checks if the main page is a posts or a Page. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE. It returns TRUE when the main blog page is being displayed and the `Settings->Reading->Front page` displays is set to "Your latest posts", or when is set to "A static page" and the "Front Page" value is the current Page being displayed.

Hence now the code is as follows.

```
<?php
if(is_front_page() || is_home())
{
    // The Code will execute if it is a 'Front Page'
    // OR
    // if the page is a 'Home Page'
}

if(is_front_page() && is_home())
{
    // Here the code will execute if the page is 
    // A Front Page and as well as the Home Page
}
?>
```

Hence it depends on the situation of how you need to display the video over the page and to toggle around the condition that works on.

Or you try `is_page()` condition and that will make up the trick for you.

// When any single Page is being displayed.

```
is_page();
```

// When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed.

```
is_page( 42 );
```

// When the Page with a post_title of "Contact" is being displayed.

```
is_page( 'Contact' );
```

// When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.

```
is_page( 'about-me' );
```

Hope this explanation would be clear for you to understand better.

Thanks:) Happy coding.

Comment: Thank you. What I ended up doing was making a separate page as the homepage instead of the theme default one. Then I used is_page(homepage) and it worked.

Comment: @user1968657. If you find that this issue is a typical issue you can add up the the vote to +1 even if you have marked as a correct answer since the same issue might occur for some other developers to so that they find easy to rectify it and resolve the Error. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The order of the statements here is critical, try flipping them around such as:

```
if(is_front_page() || is_home())
```

You can also use:

```
if(!is_front_page() && is_home())
```

Comment: Also tried this, couldn't get this to work either.  I'm using the goexplore wordpress theme. [link] (http://para.llel.us/themes/goexplore/demo/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
  // Default homepage
}
```

Comment: Tired this, couldn't get it to work. For some reason I think the theme I'm using ties with the blog with recent post and frontpage with recent posts all together and they're not separated.

Comment: What about assigning a home page manualy in Settings->Reading to a static page. Then create a template for that page, and copy, i guess, home.php file into it. The conditional would be like if ( is_page_template() ) { // your code }